# Stored procedure to return output parameter with description of error encountered

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

if below exception raised how it shall store in fourth output parameter?How to call output parameter and store exception description in an output parameter.

```
call sp_test('abc') 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test(xyz character varying(256), status OUT varchar(20) ,
 errMessage OUT varchar(50))
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE 
val1 varchar;
if val1 > 127 then
 RAISE EXCEPTION 'Requested schema name exceeds system maximum.Requested length is % while system max 
 length is 127.',val1;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

In my limited knowledge, you cannot do an OUT if you decide to go with raising an exception, because then it aborts everything.

Meanwhile what is your thought process behind returning this message in the out parameter as well as raising an exception?